# What is the meaning of `malloc(): corrupted top size`

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am trying to append a struct pointer to a dynamically allocated array. After that I return the struct pointer that was added to the array. This is then dereferenced and put into a variable that I want to print out. My problem is that when I try to access a value (i.e. `struct.id`) the compiler tells me `malloc(): corrupted top size` and `Aborted (core dumped)`.

Everywhere I have looked so far simply answered how to *fix* the problem, but I can't seem to figure out what it actually means or just find very vague definitions that don't help me. Also none of the solutions work for my specific condition.Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: It means that you have corrupted some heap metadata in the memory by writing to some locations you are not allowed to write. This metadata is implementation specific.

Comment: Apparently you tried to write outside the memory allocated. `strcut whatever *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr); ptr[1] = INVALID ACCESS;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the meaning of `malloc(): corrupted top size`

It means that your program has invoked ***U***ndefined ***B***ehaviour most likely by accessing the allocated memory block outside its bounds.

But it can also be caused by something else (for example unrelated memory access changing the memory containing `malloc`ed memory metadata).

> Also none of the solutions work for my specific condition.Aborted
> (core dumped)

It is one of the ways UB can express itself. It is not "your condition". You need to find what is invoking the UB.